# One click toggle for windows High Contrast mode

Tags: windows-10, accessibility, quickbooks

My mother-in-law has macular degeneration (losing vision).  Some applications on windows 10 are easier in high contrast mode while others are not. In QuickBooks 2019 for her small business some individual feature windows are easier to read in high contrast on or off.  So it would be ideal to be able to toggle it on and off.

Is there a program that can toggle high contrast mode on or off in one click or pressing a function key?

Comment: You can use WinKey and + to turn on Magnifier and - to turn off.  Work in QuickBooks here.  Does that help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcut:  Left alt + left shift + printscreen